# can't connect to compute engine old image

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

It's been a while since i connect to my compute engine. when i use gcutil, it prompt me for a password, which i have forgotten. So, i deleted google_compute_engine.pub and google_compute_engine from my .ssh/ directory, and also the metadata field on compute engine.

My problem is: 
if i create a brand new VM, i can connect to it just fine. However, if i create a vm based on an existing image, i'm getting

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm using this command to connect:

```
gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="xxxx" ssh  --zone="us-central1-b" "testxxx"
```

am i out of luck??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Try the Section [SSH Errors](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting)

i solved my problem trying a fresh user.

Have fun :)